# Не присваивается значение input в JS

Tags: javascript, html

Не могу понять ошибку. [Пример на JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34ybttuy/)

JS:

```
var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
var second = document.getElementById("second").value

var ev = document.getElementById("evaluate");

ev.onclick= function() {
  var res = Number(first) + Number(second);
  document.getElementById("result").value = res;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="first">+<input type="text" id="second">=<input type="text" id="result">
        <button id="evaluate">Evaluate</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ev = document.getElementById("evaluate");
ev.onclick= function() {
    var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
var second = document.getElementById("second").value

  var res = Number(first) + Number(second);
  document.getElementById("result").value = res;
}
```